# Python33 - Performance with huge scripts

Tags: python, performance

I was wondering if it's better to have one huge file with 2000+ lines of code or split it up in multiple modules. I currently have a website with all things behind it like the server, database access and templating. I am now passing the 2000-lines mark and I am wondering if it's "good practise" or just plain better to split similar modules into different files.

Currently, I have about 10 python files all with different functionalities, but I am wondering if it's better to put them in the same python file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imported modules are cached; it doesn't make much of any difference to the performance of your script if you split it up into separate modules. Only the first import of a module has a minimal loading impact. It is certainly not worth the price you'd pay in diminished maintainability of one large monolithic script.

Focus on the performance bottlenecks instead; the inner loops of your algorithm.

Comment: So having lots of separate modules is probably the optimal way just for readability and structural integrity. I can imagine it will help teams work better too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I guess that depends on what you wanna do. Maintaining several modules can get complicated as well, as you have to check which other modules are imported in the submodules and so on. So in some cases, it could be easier to maintain in fewer modules. As this is a question of personal taste and the efficiency already was answered, I would only give the advice, to have all imports in a main file, and to have those subroutines in modules, that you use more than once and that could be helpful in another programm.

Comment: This is good advice too, and I get why you say this. Having all imports in the main file is clear and when import errors occur you can easily handle them.